# How to filter dataframe by splitting categories of a columns into sets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
Prop_ID    Unit_ID      Prop_Usage                     Unit_Usage
1          1            RESIDENTIAL                    RESIDENTIAL
1          2            RESIDENTIAL                    COMMERCIAL
1          3            RESIDENTIAL                    INDUSTRIAL
1          4            RESIDENTIAL                    RESIDENTIAL
2          1            COMMERCIAL                     RESIDENTIAL
2          2            COMMERCIAL                     COMMERCIAL
2          3            COMMERCIAL                     COMMERCIAL
3          1            INDUSTRIAL                     INDUSTRIAL
3          2            INDUSTRIAL                     COMMERCIAL
4          1            RESIDENTIAL - COMMERCIAL       RESIDENTIAL
4          2            RESIDENTIAL - COMMERCIAL       COMMERCIAL
4          3            RESIDENTIAL - COMMERCIAL       INDUSTRIAL
5          1            COMMERCIAL / RESIDENTIAL       RESIDENTIAL
5          2            COMMERCIAL / RESIDENTIAL       COMMERCIAL
5          3            COMMERCIAL / RESIDENTIAL       INDUSTRIAL
5          4            COMMERCIAL / RESIDENTIAL       COMMERCIAL
```

One property may have more than 1 unit. That means units are the subcategory of properties. I want to filter rows where `Prop_Usage` does not match with `Unit_Usage`. We have a category in `Prop_Usage` column that's `RESIDENTIAL - COMMERCIAL` then `Unit_Usage` can be either `RESIDENTIAL` or `COMMERCIAL`. Similarly for `COMMERCIAL / RESIDENTIAL`.

Expected Output:

```
Prop_ID    Unit_ID      Prop_Usage                   Unit_Usage
1          2            RESIDENTIAL                  COMMERCIAL
1          3            RESIDENTIAL                  INDUSTRIAL
2          1            COMMERCIAL                   RESIDENTIAL
3          2            INDUSTRIAL                   COMMERCIAL
4          3            RESIDENTIAL - COMMERCIAL     INDUSTRIAL
5          3            COMMERCIAL / RESIDENTIAL     INDUSTRIAL
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `in` statement in [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df = df[~df.apply(lambda x: x['Unit_Usage'] in x['Prop_Usage'], axis=1)]
```

Or use `zip` in list comprehension:

```
df = df[[not a in b for a, b in zip(df['Unit_Usage'], df['Prop_Usage'])]]
```

---

```
print (df)
    Prop_ID  Unit_ID                Prop_Usage   Unit_Usage
1         1        2               RESIDENTIAL   COMMERCIAL
2         1        3               RESIDENTIAL   INDUSTRIAL
4         2        1                COMMERCIAL  RESIDENTIAL
8         3        2                INDUSTRIAL   COMMERCIAL
11        4        3  RESIDENTIAL - COMMERCIAL   INDUSTRIAL
14        5        3  COMMERCIAL / RESIDENTIAL   INDUSTRIAL
```